# Is there any XOR option for Boolean Modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bmesh

Let say we got two object, I want to get the sum of the difference for calculating error between two meshes. As the sum of **red and blue area** following image showed:

[image: XOR]

Somehow the Boolean Modifier doesn't contain this option. I know it can be work by two ways:

1. Use *Difference bool* on each object with a duplicated one, and *Union* them.
2. Union both object first and subtract the *intersect* part.

But both of the method need a duplicated copy of mesh for reference, the second one even encounter the *Overlapping issue*.

Is there any easier way to get the XOR behavior in boolean modifier or similar function.